# Ordering Records with Same Date Using Second Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, arel

I have an application with many Galleries. Each gallery has a start_date DateTime field.

For legacy reasons, the time of all start_dates is midnight.

```
Thu, 10 Jul 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

I need to order the galleries by date, so a user can shuffle back and forth across them using a 'older' and 'newer' link. Galleries are ordered based on start_date:

```
scope :start_date_ascending, -> { order(start_date: :asc) }
scope :start_date_descending, -> { order(start_date: :desc) }
```

My problem is that there is no clear older or newer gallery when there are multiple galleries with the same date. In such cases I cannot predict the order that Galleries with the same date are returned in, so moving across multiple galleries with the same date becomes random and error-prone.

I have scope set up to find newer and older galleries:

```
scope :newer_than, -> (gallery){ where.not(id:gallery).where('start_date >= :gallery_start_date', gallery_start_date:gallery.start_date) }
scope :older_than, -> (gallery){ where.not(id:gallery).where('start_date < :gallery_start_date', gallery_start_date:gallery.start_date) }
```

And I find the next and previous galleries like this:

```
def self.next_newer(gallery)
  Gallery.newer_than(gallery).start_date_ascending.limit(1).first
end

def self.next_older(gallery)
  Gallery.older_than(gallery).start_date_descending.limit(1).first
end
```

So it seems to me I need a secondary way to order the galleries that are the same date. It doesn't matter what order that is - it could simply be their ids.

How can I handle this situation so that galleries with the same date appear in the query in a predictable, fixed order so that `next_newer` and `next_older` move through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can sort with a second criteria, `name` for example and if available, or even `id`

```
scope :start_date_ascending, -> { order(start_date: :asc, name: :asc) }
scope :start_date_descending, -> { order(start_date: :desc, name: :asc) }
```

note on the `start_date_descending` scope it can be nice to keep name `asc`, so despite of the descending date order we keep a alphabetical order

And for the next and previous gallery, if you can store an array, you can get your ordered ids and iterate through them

```
ids = Gallery.start_date_ascending.pluck :id
```

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this would indeed handle the order, it doesn't solve the problem of the query. I still need a way to make sure the queries return Galleries previous or subsequent to the given gallery. How can I then query for Galleries that have a start_date before the given gallery OR ( have the same date AND have a name previous to the given gallerie's)

Comment: Can you store an array of `id`s? `ids = Gallery.start_date_ascending.pluck :id`. Then iterate through that array

Answer (score 1):

Based on @BengaminSinclaire's suggestion:

```
  def self.next_newer(gallery)
    ascending_ids = Gallery.start_date_ascending.pluck :id
    current_index = ascending_ids.index(gallery.id)
    Gallery.find(ascending_ids[current_index+1]) if current_index < ascending_ids.length - 1
  end

  def self.next_older(gallery)
    ascending_ids = Gallery.start_date_ascending.pluck :id
    current_index = ascending_ids.index(gallery.id)
    Gallery.find(ascending_ids[current_index-1]) if current_index > 0
  end
```